# Google Cloud - can't enter my password to connect to MySQL instance on Cloud Shell

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

I'm just going through the quickstart tutorial to creating MySQL instances here: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/quickstart?hl=en_US

I was able to create a MySQL instance and open the Cloud Shell terminal from the console. But when I get to step 3 on the tutorial ("Enter your root password"), Cloud Shell does not let me type anything in. All it says is:

```
Connecting to database with SQL user [root].Enter password:
```

I cannot enter any characters. I can press Enter, but then I get:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'12.345.678.90' (using password: YES)
```

This happens whether I load the console on Chrome or Edge.

I also tried downloading MySQL Workbench and creating a connection using the IP address displayed on my list of MySQL instances and the password I set up, but I get a generic "access denied" error that doesn't tell me why the connection failed. The default connection method for the connection is "StandardConnection (TCP/IP)" and the port is "3306", if that matters.

Comment: Do you mean, "you don't see any characters on the screen (star * or something else) when you hit keys on your keyboard"?

Comment: @guillaume-blaquiere Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: @guillaume-blaquiere - actually, let me correct myself. No, I mean it literally does not type anything --- as though I were trying to enter text into a field with a character limit of 0. Thanks for responding btw.

Comment: That I didn't understand is this "I cannot enter any characters. I can press Enter, but then I get:". How can you say that you cannot enter any character? Can you also paste a screenshot of your CloudSQL connections configuration?

Answer (score 4):

Just type in your password. It won't show up in the terminal, not even '*'. After you enter the password correctly, hit enter and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can type your password, simply nothing is printed to the screen in order to hide your password from being visible. Not even '*' characters are printed, so that the length of your password cannot be seen. This is common for command line tools (e.g. linux login is the same, as is sudo, as is SSH). Enter works because it indicates the password is complete, and returns the console to the normal mode.

Comment: This answer does not seem to contribute anything new compared to the existing one.